# ¿Como leer un archivo txt y obtener un valor en especifico?

Tags: php

trabajo en un sistema de registro utilizando archivos txt como base de datos, al almacenar los datos de los usuarios en el archivo txt se ven de la siguiente manera

> usuario: angel|correo:e@e.e|clave:12|usuario:
>   angel|correo:e@e.e|clave:12|

para validar que el usuario no este ya almacenado leo este archivo mostrandome la linea anteriormente colocada y de esa linea necesito todos los valores que tengan el indice usuario:angel o cualquier otro valor

esos valores almacenarlos en un arreglo para comararlos con el usuario que esta llegando desde `POST`

este es el codigo que utilizo para leer el archivo

```
$data = '../usuarios/usuarios.txt';
$allData = fopen($data,'r');

    while (!feof($allData)) {
        $all = fgets($allData);
        $all2 = explode('|', $all);
        echo $all;
    }
```

luego quiero separar esa cadena que llega por el simbolo

> |

y me da error

```
Notice: Array to string conversion
```

Comment: Probablemente te sale ese error por que en `echo $all;` la variable `$all` no es una cadena, en lugar de `echo` usa `print_r` o `var_dump`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te interesa el dato que hay después de usuario, puedes hacer algo así:

- Un `explode` sobre `|`
- Recorres los pares haciendo dentro otro `explode` sobre `:`
- En ese segundo `explode` verificas si el valor del índice `0` es `usuario` sacas el dato asociado, que estará en el índice `1`
- Se usará también `trim` para limpiar los espacios en blanco que sobran

#### Código

```
$str="usuario: angel|correo:e@e.e|clave:12|usuario: angel|correo:e@e.e|clave:12";
$arr = explode("|",$str);

foreach($arr as $v)
{
    $parts=explode(':',$v);
    if(trim($parts[0])=="usuario"){
        $usrName=trim($parts[1]);
        echo $usrName.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**Salida:**

```
angel
angel
```

Ahí ya puedes usar `$usrName` para lo que deseas.

Espero te sirva.